# Picklist value determined by formula

Tags: picklist, dashboard

Ultimately I'm looking to create a dashboard for accounts in Red/Yellow/Green criteria based on the trend of rolling 10 week sales.  I was easily able to create a text formula field to assign a text value for "Red"/"Yellow"/"Green" and it works great, however it is just boring ole text.  Instead I would like to have a picklist automatically populated based on a formula.  Since with a the picklist I can control the colors.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just show the Red, Yellow, Green images based on your picklist of the Red, yellow, green text, then you can use something like this

```
IF( 
    ISPICKVAL(YourObject.YourTextRicklist__c, "Red"), IMAGE("/resource/yourRedImage.png", "red",32,32), 
    IF( 
        ISPICKVAL(YourObject.YourTextRicklist__c, "Yellow"), IMAGE("/resource/yourYellowImage.png", "yellow",32,32),
        IMAGE("/resource/yourGreenImage.png", "green",32,32)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To control picklist values based on a formula you just need to set up some workflow rules that fire for the various value and change the picklist as appropriate.  Of course, @Dunc44's approach of using an image is the standard for doing this sort of ratings change.

Comment: The problem with Workflow Rule Field updates in this scenario are two: 1) you can't set a picklist value by formula, so you'd need at least two rules/updates, and possibly one per PL value; 2) Formulas update in real-time, and WF Field Updates only fire on record save.

Comment: I've got a field setup for text of "Red"/"Yellow"/"Green", which works great.  So now I've setup a workflow to say if fieldname CONTAINS red - trigger a workflow to update my pick list field to the red value.  Evaluation criteria is "created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria".  I've also updated my text formula to force an update, ergo to trigger the workflow action, however no update.  Is my use of a text field causing the issue?

Comment: Editing the text formula won't trigger an update.  Formula fields don't ever really change, they're just evaluated when the record loads.  Trying picking a recording and toggling the values back and forth and see if that works for you.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor you're correct you'd need to create a workflow for each picklist value.  I wouldn't go this route either, changing the text formula field to an image makes more sense to me for the ratings idea.